# How to enlarge an img via onclick (generated image from dataurl.. code link in desc)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I know it's easy how to enlarge an image via onclick when there's an image tag but i'm generating images from dataurl saved with the canvas and have no idea how to target each image. Please check out the link and view page source. Thanks guys.

http://praxis.cit.ie/~josephwinfield/project1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelectorAll to get a nodelist of all img elements that you've added to your #graphs array.

Then you can iterate this nodelist and process each img element as desired.

```
var imgs=document.querySelectorAll("#graphs img") 

for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){

    // get each img element

    var img=imgs[i];

    // do whatever processing you need to do here

}
```